# DRF Serializer validation by database column

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a custom serializer like this--

```
class customSerializers(serializers.Serializer):
    token = serializers.CharField(max_length=12)
```

And I have a model like this

```
class UserToken(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=12)
```

Now I want to validate my customSerializers token field. The token value has to exists in the UserToken model and belongs to the  current user.

** I Don't want to use model serializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass user to serializer, then implement validation on the field:

```
class CustomSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    token = serializers.CharField(max_length=12)

    def validate_token(self, value):
        user_id = self.context.get('user_id')
        return UserToken.objects.filter(user__id=user_id, token=value).exists()
```

in your view:

```
serializer = CustomSerializer(... , context={'user_id': request.user.id})
if serializer.is_valid():
    ...
```